# How do I remove a tag from a cached item when using AppFabric

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

I've got objects cached by multiple tags.  I can request them but I want to remove one specific tag from all of the objects that were returned with `GetObjectsByTag(tag, region)`.  I can't figure out how to either simply remove the tag or `Put` the thing back in with only the other tags (anything I didn't just query with).  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific API for managing the tags on an item, and I suspect that even if you were to create one using extension methods, essentially it would boil down to:

1. Get the object
2. Get the `IEnumerable<DataCacheTag>` from the object
3. Remove the tags you don't want
4. Put the object with the updated set of tags

There might be a way to do it if you poke around in the AppFabric assemblies with Reflector, but if you get a problem I doubt you'd be supported by Microsoft.